# Best way to store >1MB array in iCloud?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, icloud, cloudkit

Up until now, I have been using the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` Apple offers to store an array of text and images into iCloud, and I likewise, download that information back to my app when needed (multiple device support, etc).

However, I have now realized that `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`'s storage limits, are not allowing for as much info as I need to be stored. I have one array of text and another of images (the text array can store some pretty large amounts of text, due to the size of the text), but the image array can't bear a high-quality image.

My question is, what is the best way to very simply store a NSArray into iCloud, without reaching any considerably small storage limits? I have looked into CloudKit, which uses record style storage, which I could adapt my app to use, but would this be the best way?

Thank you.

Comment: According to the docs for `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, the total amount of space available in your app’s key-value store, for a given user, is 1 MB. Therefore `CloudKit` sounds like it would be a good option given that you are already using `iCloud` so your users will already have an `iCloud ID` and the storage Apple gives for free starts at 5GB. Unfortunately, I've not used `CloudKit` so have no code to share and don't know enough about it's limitations.

Comment: CloudKit, I agree, sounds like the solution, but I don't know where to start. I have an iCloud Container, and I am saving a record to a record type I created in the Dashboard, but how would I retrieve the information for the record? It seems to require a record ID?

Comment: The best info I've seen on `CloudKit` was the WWDC 2014 videos from Apple which went through how to use it. Get the videos from: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ . The videos are `#208 Introducing CloudKit` and `#231 Advanced CloudKit`. There is also a Ray Wenderlich tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial

Comment: Taking a look at the links you provided now, question, because of the database structure of CloudKit, what would be the format I would store an NSArray as? Meaning, would I have to create a record and just keep overwriting that record with the new modified array each time? Just seems like CloudKit wasn't meant for storing data like this. With NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore I was able to set the array with a key, which seemed a bit more efficient. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not an expert on `CloudKit` as I haven't used it but what I took away from the videos is that it's more like `CoreData` in concept but very much simpler in execution in that it hands responsibility for functionality over to the app. So I would expect each object in the array to be a different record in the database (and you can have different record types) rather than storing an `NSArray` directly. Then you might load the `NSArray` and use the `NSArray` internally in the app (or possibly use the records directly; but cached yourself?).  But I could be wrong...

Comment: Makes sense, as that is how database structures like this should be used. The key word there, should be. Creating a new record for each entry I have in my continually growing array would seem overkill. By uploading the array directly, I would be simulating the functionality of NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore, but dramatically increasing my storage capabilities, which is exactly what I need. But would Apple approve that..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question with the help of Robotic Cat. CloudKit seems to be the best answer to my situation. I have been able to use the private database of my custom iCloud container to store and retrieve info. At this point, my only dilemma is whether to go the traditional route and create a new record for each entry to what would normally go to my array, or to just track changes in my app, and upload/overwrite the entire array as one record.

Comment: I would try to minimise attempting to overwrite all the records when you save (there are daily `CloudKit` transfer limits perhaps?) but rather carry out incremental downloads and uploads. It probably means having a singleton with background, asynchronous synchronisation with `CloudKit` - this would also allow simultaneous use by the private and public databases.

Comment: Also, I am amazed how quickly you got `CloudKit` up and running - `CoreData` would have taken longer.

Comment: It has been pretty smooth. The way I am going though now is to bypass all local storage that I have been doing, and then just upload these strings/data directly to iCloud as a record, with the name of the string as the recordID. Will have to overhaul a bunch of my code though, so that isn't fun.